# ARM Cortex-M4F sqrtf uses double

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, arm, cortex-m

I am working on code for a arm Cortex-M4F with a fpv4-sp-d16 and ABI=hard.

As i was looking with Ozone into my elf file I found that my code uses some double precision functions: eg. `__aeabi_dmul`

If I don't use `sqrtf` or use the *-ffast-math* option, the double support function are no longer linked.
Since I do not know what other implications the *-ffast-math* option  introduces, I would like to not use that option.

Are there any other option to get a float sqrt function?

Using ARM-GCC 10 2021.10 with *-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Os -fsingle-precision-constant -Wfloat-equal -Wdouble-promotion*

I found in the Disassembly that inside of `sqrtf` the `__aeabi_ddiv` is called.

The suggested solution:

```
float sqrtf_wrap(float x) __attribute__((optimize("fast-math")));
float sqrtf_wrap(float x)
{
    if(x >= 0.0f)
        return __builtin_sqrtf(x);
    else
       return NAN;
}
```

does not change the build result: `__aeabi_ddiv` is still used.

**Update/Solution**

I found a question where one had the same problem:
[Double division in sqrtf? [UPDATE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691780/double-division-in-sqrtf-update)

His solution: Directly calling `__ieee754_sqrtf` works(there is directly the VSQRT.F32 instruction) for me as well.

Further more I found that `sqrtf` with *-fno-math-errno* also works .

Unfortunately a wrapper with local optimization options does Not work - seems that the optimization is not applied to the called math function.

Therefore I will use
`__ieee754_sqrtf` instead of `sqrtf`

Comment: Is is possible that you use `double` somewhere else (by accident) and when you remove the `fsqrt()` they are either no longer there or optimized out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sqrtf` otherwise it will have to convert it to `double` and call the sqrt.

`-ffast-math` is not needed to compile correctly - but it enables more optimizations and breaks strict IEEE conformance (https://simonbyrne.github.io/notes/fastmath/)

Example:

```
float mysqrtf(float x)
{
    return sqrtf(x);
}
```

Resulting code:

- Without `-ffast-math`

```
mysqrtf:
        vcmp.f32        s0, #0
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        vmov.f32        s15, s0
        bmi     .L10    //call sqrtf if parameter is negative
        vsqrt.f32       s0, s15
        bx      lr
.L10:
        b       sqrtf
```

- With `-ffast-math`

```
mysqrtf:
        vsqrt.f32       s0, s0  //no checks is parameter is negative. If it is it will generate the exception (Invalid Operation or Inexact exceptions)
        bx      lr
```

Command line options: `-O2 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb  <-ffast-math> -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16`

Comment: @artlessnoise no mate. Without fast-math it is calling `sqrtf` only in some edge cases (basically to correctly handle NaNs, set `errno` if needed etc). It answers the OPs question. It eliminates conversion to doubles and in **most** cases uses hardware FPU instruction. I do not see any complaints about linker problems in the OPs question

Comment: @artlessnoise no again. It is only called if the parameter is wrong (ie negative or NaN). If you pass correct parameter `vsqrt` will be executed.  EOD.

Comment: without a  minimal repeatable answer from the OP we cannot describe why they are getting double math it is probably something trivial like 1.234 vs 1.234F.   I see this as the answer to the question....thus far.  cortex-m4 sqrtf being used without any doubles showing up

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/zj3r8fsYW) which I feel is a good fit to your question.

#include <math.h>

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
# ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
float sqrtf_wrap(float x) __attribute__((optimize("fast-math")));
# else
float sqrtf_wrap(float x) __attribute__((optimize("1"), optimize("fast-math")));
# endif
float sqrtf_wrap(float x)
{
    if(x >= 0.0f)
      return __builtin_sqrtf(x);
    else 
     return NAN;  
}
#else
 /* ??? link error at least ??? */
#endif
```

This avoids the call to the internal library 'sqrtf()' which is possibly responsible for the use of double utility functions (such as `__aeabi_dmul`) needed for a 'single precision' floating point unit.

The wrapper is,

1. Fairly efficient
2. Avoids linking `sqrtf()` and any dependant calls.
3. It will return 'NAN' when called with in-appropriate arguments.
4. Does not enable fast-math globally.
5. *errno* is not set on abnormal arguments.

It is dependant on gcc features and is not as maintainable as just a standard `sqrtf()` call.  The main benefit is less code linked in the binary.  The presence of functions such as `__aeabi_dmul` often indicate unintended use of doubles, which is important on a *single precision* FPU for both code density and speed (accepting less precision). That is to say, it can be an important maintenance feature to examine the lack of `double` support functions in a linked object or map file and so the wrapper might be an necessary evil.

Also, it is beneficial to use `-Wdouble-promotion` on a CPU like this especially to determine that float constants have a trailing 'f' to specify single precision (or `float` versus `double` constant).

Comment: It can be [difficult to get fast-math to apply locally](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50782) but as [godbolt show](https://godbolt.org/z/vhEPsThqq), this works..

Comment: 1. It is not IEEEE.... compliant. 2. It does not set errno 3. wrong comparison. 4. It is only gcc.

Comment: 4 was already stated (but it likely works with clang).  I fixed 3.  It is unlikely people care about 2, but now noted.  In regards to 1, it will return NAN on error cases and worse issues also apply to use of `-ffast-math` and no handling.

Comment: It does not work for me: 
sqrtf is still linked and with it the double utility functions

Comment: @user3653656 Can you use `objdump -S target.o` and post the generated assembler?  Alternatively, you can use the godbolt link and update compiler options to exactly as you use to see if it affects things.  As the [other link shows](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50782), it can be difficult to get fast math to apply locally as it can affect the calling function as well, which can restrict optimizations.  Oh, most definitely you need to turn optimizations on.